# Is there any religious significance of saffron flag as per our scriptures?

Tags: history, culture, symbolism

Modern Hindu organisations usually use saffron triangular flag as a unanimously accepted symbol of Hinduism. However, does the flag or colour have any significance as per authentic Hindu scriptures?

Comment: saffron is the color worn by sanyasis, it represents that Rajo Guna (associated with red/saffron color) has left their body (and onto their clothes). It denotes renunciation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Historicity of the Bhagwa flag](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16434/historicity-of-the-bhagwa-flag)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about flag, but the color sure have important place in Sanatana Dharma. All Rishis/Munis used to wear yellowish color'ed clothes which is nearly same as Saffron color. Here is a reference from Rigveda [Suktam 10 Hymn 136](https://archive.org/stream/hymnsrigveda00unkngoog#page/n588/mode/2up):

> मुनयो वातरशनाः पिशङ्गा वसते मला ।
>
> वातस्यानु ध्राजिं यन्ति यद्देवासो अविक्षत ॥२॥
>
> The Munis, girdled with the wind, wear garments soiled of yellow hue. They, following the wind's swift course go where the Gods have gone before.

**Note:** The reference to this hymn I found from wikipedia article on [Sannyasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sannyasa#cite_note-gsg-18). As per my understanding from the article, It seems the English word for "soiled of yellow hue" is Saffron. That is why they referred that as Saffron when mentioning the short translation of that hymn. Hence I put Saffron in bracket since there is no direct mentioning of the word in the book but it was Wikipedia all alone.

Comment: Thank you, abhivadan 

Comment: @user19 You're welcome. There is one more reference, I'll try to dig and add to my answer.

Comment: No offence, but I think that saffron in the translation is more of an example. The word Pishanga refers to any yellow hued substance while Saffron usually goes by Sanskrit names as Kumkuma or Priyangu. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra: the usage of words in vedic sanskrit is different from that subsequent classical sanskrit.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Nevertheless, since the word "saffron" is in brackets, I would advise cross-referencing it with other translations. Especially since it concenrs Griffith’s translation

Comment: @GabeHiemstra: You are right, it can be reddish or yellowish (https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=pizaGga&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3).  However, as I said, we don't know the exact usage of that word at that point of time.

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection, the word saffron looks like an interpolation by poster here. I wonder what the motive is.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra Updated the answer; Just be assured there is no motive.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto With motive I meant reasons pointing to commentarial/explanatory sources not indicated in the answer, so thanks for adding the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

The Ochre color, which is very close to Saffron, has been prescribed as the color of an ascetic's garments.

> 6 A wandering ascetic should wander forth according to the rule,
>   abandoning his relatives and free of possessions. 17 Going into the
>   wilderness, 18 he has his head shaven except for the topknot; 19 wears
>   a loin cloth; 20 resides in one place during the rainy season ; 21 **and
>   wears ochre clothes**
>
> **Baudhayana Dharma Sutras 2.11.26.11-21**

There can be similar verses in other scriptures as well and such verses must be the reason why the saffron/ochre color gradually got associated with the Hindu Sannyasis (ascetics).
Not sure though about the reasons for flags to be of a particular design.

However, note that it is forbidden to perform Vedic rituals etc dressed in garments of that color.

> When someone engages in the soft recitation of prayers, performs a
>   sacrifice, or accepts a gift dressed in ochre clothes––**an oblation
>   made in this way at a rite to gods or ancestors does not reach its
>   deity.**
>
> Baudhayana Dharma Sutras 2.15.5

But then again you have to understand that saffron/ochre is mostly associated with Sannyasis and the Sannyasis abandon fire sacrifice, Vedic rituals among many other things.

Comment: *"But then again you have to understand that saffron/ochre is mostly associated with Sannyasis and the Sannyasis abandon fire sacrifice, Vedic rituals among many other things."* No it's not associated with Sanyasis, they just happen to wear same saffron clothes like our rishis used to wear. read my answer above.

Comment: Which Sanskrit words in the mantra in ur answer refer to them wearing saffron colored clothes?@TheLittleNaruto And, yes Saffron is associated primarily with the Sannyasis. It is seen as a color related to Vairagya.